# Underlined journal names in bibliographystyle of apacite with natbibapa option

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using these commands:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

and later:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

I would like to keep the natbib option because my text already uses citep and citet a lot. The reason why I am using apacite is because I need ampersand ('&') between author names (instead of 'and'). So the citiations in text and paranthesis are correct, but the References section has a strange format:

1) Journal names are underlined,

2) Pulications with several authors uses "..." to abbreviate names.

I would like the bibliographystyle not to underline Journal names  but rather follow "normal" conventions. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get any underlining. Perhaps you have `\usepackage{ulem}` in your preamble: if so, remove it.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was using ulem, and, removing it did the trick.

Comment: @tw: you still can load `ulem` and use its functionalities. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

The package `apacite` does no underlining. The problem could be in you loading

```
\usepackage{ulem}
```

Note that underlining for emphasis is a typographical device that eminent typographers consider *very* bad. It can have its uses for special notation, but it should *never* be used for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `biblatex` with `style=apa` and `natbib` option. For the problem created by `ulem`, if you need its functionalities, you can load it with option `normalem` or use `soulutf8` instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt,american, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{soulutf8}%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{apatest.bib}
@Article{BRW,
Title = {The determinants of undergraduate degree performance: how important is gender?},
Author = {Barrow, Michael and Reilly, Barry and Woodfield, Ruth},
Journal = {British Educational Research Journal},
Year = {2009},
Number = {4},
Pages = {575-597},
Volume = {35},

Doi = {10.1080/01411920802642322},
Eprint = {link},
Url = {link}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{apatest.bib}

\begin{document}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. \cite{McNabb}.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `natbib` is a compatibility option that emulates natbib commands, whose functionality is otherwise available in biblatex.

Comment: Note that the OP's problem with the underlined journal name (and volume number too, by the way) is *not* solved by switching from apacite/natbib/bibtex to apa/biblatex/biber. The OP's problem arises because he/she is loading the `ulem` package. Sure enough, if `ulem` is included in *your* MWE the same problem arises as well. The real solution, then, is not to load the `ulem` package...

Comment: That was not said in the initial question… Anyway she/he should move to biblatex, in my opinion.

Comment: Whether or not a move to biblatex is advisable is entirely separate from getting the underlining-instead-of-italics issue fixed, right?

Comment: @Mico: Absolutely.