# unsrt bibtex mode with underlined

Tags: bibtex, underline

I have a problem with the underlines in the bibliography.
I am using the package

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

in report mode. And introducing the bibliography like this

```
@incollection{HandbookAdvancedCeramics,
editor = "Shigeyuki Somiya",
booktitle = "Handbook of Advanced Ceramics",
publisher = "Academic Press",
edition = "Second Edition",
year = "2013"
}
```

or

```
@phdthesis{OxidationZrB2SiCUHT,
    title    = {Oxidation Behavior of Zirconium Diboride - Silicon Carbide Based Materials at Ultra-High Temperatures},
    school   = {University of Virginia},
    author   = {Kathleen N. Shugart},
    year     = {2014} 
}
```

and it appears like this in the bibliography page.
[image]
but it seems a bit random. Sometimes the underlined is the title and other times it is the name of the magazine.

Anyway, I do not want it to appear underlined. How can I correct it?

Comment: The `unsrt` style or the `report` documentclass do not produce underlined bibliographies normally. That means that something else in the document is causing the underlines. Please post a complete, small example document that shows this behavior, with just one reference in it and nothing else, which can be compiled and results in a bibliography with underlines. With such an example the community here can identify what the problem is, without it we can only guess.

Comment: One guess would be that you have `\usepackage{ulem}` in your document, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193317/underlined-journal-names-in-bibliographystyle-of-apacite-with-natbibapa-option. Replacing that with `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` might help.

Comment: Perfect @Marijn. That package works perfectly for my.